# Python not finding MySQLdb on OSX..?

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

Using pip I installed mysql-python, got:

```
Successfully installed MySQL-python-1.2.5
```

However when I try to import MySQLdb I get:

```
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

locate MySQLdb gives me:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb
```

Why is Python not finding the module?

Thanks!
Gil.

Comment: do you have more than one python installed?

Comment: Yes, I have Python3 as well.

Comment: Then the problem is the mySQL was installed in python2.7 and your import command is using python3.  Ensure that you are in python2.7 when you run "import mySQLdb". goodluck

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I am. Calling /usr/bin/python, which is 2.7. Maybe the module was installed in Python 3, but I doubt it somehow...

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/python3
import MySQLdb
Doesn't work either...

Comment: This morning I installed Python 2.7 and python-mysql from Mac Ports, and use #!/opt/kk7ds/bin/python2.7, same problem!